# How to get bot to reply to user with a (@)ping

Tags: discord.js, replit

I am trying to get a bot to respond to people with a ping in the message, for example: "@user", but everything I've tried have given me `not a function` error or `undefined` error. All the stuff I can find about it is either outdated for `discord.js` v14 or it is for `discord.py`

Here is my code:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("test")) {
        const user = message.author.userId();
        message.channel.reply(`Hello <@${user}>`)
    }
});
```

I've also attempted variations of the `.userId()` part - such as `.tag`, `.user.id`, and `.username` but all of them have come back with some sort of `undefined` error. I know it says [userId is a snowflake on discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/14.5.0/function/userMention) but I am unsure on how to use that for I am fairly new to javascript and discord.js. Also, please know that I am using Replit to host the bot and have `discord.js@14.5.0` installed.

Comment: try using `message.author.toString()` and ensure your client has mentions enabled

Answer (score 0):

So, there are a couple issues here.

## Issue 1

`message.author.userId()` is not a function. When trying to get a user's ID, you want to know what each property is returning.

`message` -> returns the Message object, which contains the data for the message.
`message.author` -> returns the User object, which contains the data for the user profile.
`message.member` -> returns the Member object, which contains the data for the guild member profile.

And so on.

In this case, you're going to want to get the `User` object: being `message.author`. You've already figured this out.

Now, the `User` Object has it's own set of properties (which you can find in the documentation at https://discord.js.org/).

The property that you are looking for is: `.id`, or in your use-case, `message.author.id`.

Your other attempts, `message.author.tag` returns the tag, `message.author.user.id` will throw an error, and `message.author.username` returns the user's username.

## Issue 2

Your second issue is the `.reply()` method that you're using. The `Channel` Object doesn't have a `.reply()` method, but the message does.

So, how you would write this code:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async(message) => {
  if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("test")) {
    // Note that I added the .toLowerCase() method to ensure you can do tEST and it still works!
    message.reply({ content: `Hello, ${message.author}!` });
  }
});
```

Also, a cool feature that discord.js has is that you can supply the `User` or `Member` Object to the content of a message, and it will automatically mention the desired person.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you!! It now works, I got confused thinking I needed to make a const statement like I had to for a different thing I have a for the bot when people say a trigger word and ping another user. Thank you for the info!